# How can I download PDF files from Google Drive to my iOS app?

Tags: swift, xcode, google-drive-api

I want to build an app that lets the user download books, and those books are located on Google Drive.

My question is: how to download pdf files from Google Drive or the internet?

Answer (score 1):

#### Answer:

*You can use the Google Drive `Files: get` method to directly download PDFs, or use the `Files: export` method to convert native Drive files to PDF.*

#### More Information:

The official Google Drive documentation<sup>[[1]](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads)</sup> only give download examples for node.js, Python and Java, but this can be used for whichever language you would like. This uses the `Files: get`<sup>[[2]](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get)</sup> method for downloading files to the local machine.

The `Files: export` method<sup>[[3]](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/export)</sup> is used for converting files of Google Drive format to another format. The MIME Types of Google Drive files are well documented<sup>[[4]](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/mime-types)</sup> and only certain files can be exported to PDF<sup>[[5]](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/ref-export-formats)</sup>.

#### References:

1. [Download files | Google Drive API v3](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads)
2. [Google Drive API - `Files: get`](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get)
3. [Google Drive API - `Files: export`](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/export)
4. [G Suite and Drive MIME Types](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/mime-types)
5. [G Suite documents and corresponding export MIME Types](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/ref-export-formats)